# Count discrete values of a char array in C

Tags: c, arrays, count, char

is there any way to count the values of a char array in discrete form?
Example: array[]={"Nick,"George","Nick") --> count=2 and not 3 as the elements of the array! Thanks :D

Comment: Any other preconditions on that? Sorting the array, then enumerating and bumping a counter with each detected change in current vs prior element is an obvious solution.

Comment: This can't compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a hash-table and traverse the list adding the elements to the hash-table.

When you are done, get the count from the hash-table.

Answer (score 0):

as 599644 answered I would suggest a hashing because it is one of the simplest way to solve the problem, you can use uthash library which is very easy to use and well-documented. 
Here is the link to it: https://troydhanson.github.io/uthash/userguide.html